# Kafka Broker marks partitions as failed

Tags: apache-kafka

I notice the message in kafka broker logs

`Partition <topic name> marked as failed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)`

My question is how and when does Kafka mark a partition as failed.
I need to monitor the logs and take action on messages.

Is this message actionable or something that can be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

> `Partition <topic name> marked as failed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)`

You can see examples of such an error message in:

- "[`ReplicaFetcher` crashing - First offset XXXXXXX is less than the next offset YYYYYYYY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57475689/6309)"
- [Apache Kafka: `kafka.common.OffsetsOutOfOrderException` when reassigning `__consumer_offsets` to new brokers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64514851/6309)

---

You could try and troubleshoot your situation, using Python for basic monitoring of Kafka with the [`kafka-python` library](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/) (`pip install kafka-python`).
That program will continuously check and print the available [brokers and the topics each broker is leading](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_concepts_and_terms).

```py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaClient
import time

def kafka_monitor(kafka_server):
    client = KafkaClient(bootstrap_servers=kafka_server)

    while True:
        metadata = client.cluster
        for broker in metadata.brokers():
            print(f"Broker: {broker.nodeId} - {broker.host}:{broker.port}")
            for topic, partition_info in metadata.partitions_for_topic(topic).items():
                if broker.nodeId == partition_info.leader:
                    print(f"    Leading topic: {topic}")

        time.sleep(10)  # Check every 10 seconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    kafka_monitor('localhost:9092')
```

That script will print the brokers and the topics they are leading every 10 seconds.
(Replace `'localhost:9092'` with the address of your Kafka server)

However, in a production environment, you would typically use a comprehensive monitoring solution like Prometheus with Grafana for visualizing metrics, or even Kafka's built-in JMX metrics along with a tool like JConsole.
Also, the [Apache Kafka distribution](https://kafka.apache.org/) includes a set of shell scripts that can help with some operations like checking topics and partitions.

Such a basic script should allow you to:

- Identify the Problem: Regularly printing the brokers and the topics they are leading will give you a basic snapshot of your Kafka cluster's state. If a broker repeatedly disappears from the leader role for some partitions, it might be experiencing issues.
- check broker health: it does provide a basic form of liveness check. If a broker is down, it won't be leading any topics.
- validate configuration: observing the broker and leader distribution might indirectly reveal some configuration issues. For example, if you see that some brokers are leading a disproportionately high number of topics, it might indicate a problem with the partition allocation or broker configuration.
- troubleshoot network: regular disappearance and reappearance of a broker may be an indicator of network instability.
- consider a broker restart or replacement: if a broker is constantly disappearing from the list, this might be a sign that the broker is unstable and needs to be restarted or replaced.